# How is MMIO initialized and MMIO accesses performed by the CPU?

Tags: memory, x86, arm, cpu

I know that there is MMIO and when I read/write to MMIO addresses I access not the system memory but HW "memory". My question is how the MMIO is set up? How does the CPU know that access at address 0x1234 must be sent to HW (and which HW?) and not to memory? Is there HW registers somewhere in cpu that does mapping? Who initializes such registers? Firmware like Das U-Boot? Or are there predefined addresses for bus controllers? Something like "i2c bus controller is always at address 0x1000 for this processor" defined in functional spec maybe?

What part of CPU is responsible for MMIO? IIUC MMU is for virtual memory and not for MMIO.

Who (EFI? u-boot?) and how told the CPU that memory access at address 0x1234 must be forwarded to (e.g.) PCI device N?

Could you also provide an example for a modern arm (or x86) architecture?

The way I see it the CPU has two states: one is immediately after reset when CPU knows nothing about hardware and the second is when CPU is well aware of MMIO and where to forward each MMIO access. How is transition from first to second state done?

Sorry for a tangled question. I'm confused.

Thank you.

Comment: There's a bit of fundamental misunderstanding here - regardless of what it's writing to, all the CPU eventually does is drive some address and data lines appropriately. It's down to the bus and system interconnect beyond to decide (based on the address) whether that data is sent to the memory controller, or to some other device. The whole point of MMIO is the "MM" part of it - i.e. it's accessible in the normal virtual address space (_not_ some special I/O space), can be remapped by the MMU, etc.

Comment: So If I understood you correctly all memory accesses are sent to front side bus controller and it's his duty to route the request to the related hw. Then the answers that I seek are in front-side bus controller functional spec. And firmware (EFI, BIOS, Das U-Boot, w/e) initializes somehow this FSB controller. Could you please provide an example? Also how do CPU caches differentiate between MMIO and memory access?

Comment: Only if you have a FSB - that's a very x86 view of the world - in ARM the memory system is all on one chip - so there is no FSB. The bus physical addressing in most ARM systems is fixed when the chip is manufactured.

Comment: In terms of how does the CPU cache "know" what addresses are IO and what are normal memory - it only knows what software tells it. It's down to the operating system and/or device drivers to corretly set up the MMU pages with a "can be cached" or "can't be cached" type properties

Comment: Thank you @Isogen74. A real world example of setting up the HW by the SW is exactly what I'm looking for. I guess I could just get something popular with open documentation like pandaboard and inspect Das U-Boot sources. I just want to know where to look. The "what software tells it" is exactly what I want to find. Also if "The bus physical addressing in most ARM systems is fixed when the chip is manufactured." then what part of chip does the differentiation?

Comment: Also does chip documentation say something like "wherever you solder to these pins would be mapeed to addresses 0x1000-0x2000"? Also about PCI host controller. Even before FW is run the PCI bar contains addresses. How does PCI host controller know where in address space to map the devices? And if FW later overwrites these addresses how does FW know where to map the devices so MMIO translatoin would be correct?

Comment: > Then what part of chip does the differentiation?

The bus hardware itself contains a mapping of which address from a given master (master trigger bus accesses) goes to which slave (slave responds to a request from a a master). So the CPU will poke address A and the bus knows that goes to the main DDR, the CPU will poke address B and the bus knows that goes to the serial UART, etc.

Comment: > Also does chip documentation say something like "wherever you solder to these pins would be mapeed to addresses 0x1000-0x2000"? Basically yes. A lot of the address end-points are inside the chip, so the logical registers for the DDR address will be implemented inside a a memory controller inside the main chip (for a typical smartphone) - what goes off chip tend to be bigger line drivers for DDR, ethernet, etc, not the original address lines.